# Get data from a table line and pass it to a form

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm a beginner PHP/HTML/JAVASCRIPT coder and I'm having problems on making a table's "Edit" button work properly, I hope you guys can help me!

Here's the story: I'm making a bootstrap table, and a for loop to get data from the database and create new rows for each line stored. The for loop also creates a button (from bootstrap) called 'edit' and when I click in this button I'm using jQuery to show a Modal with a form, which is in a div..

So, my problem is: How can I populate the modal's div (using value = "") according to the line that the user clicked in the table?

Code:

```
<table class = "table table-condensed table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th width = "20%">Nome Completo</th>
        <th>Telefone Residencial</th>
        <th>Telefone Celular</th>
        <th>Bairro</th>
        <th>Endereço</th>
        <th>Complemento</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr> 

<?php
        require("config/connection.inc.php");

        $clients = R::getAll("SELECT * FROM client");
        foreach($clients as $client) {
    ?>

    <tr>

        <td><?=$client['something']?></td>
        <td><?=$client['something']?></td>
        <td><?=$client['something']?></td>
        <td><?=$client['something']?></td>

    <td>
      <!--- How can i get the ID of the client clicked and send to the modal's div form ??--->
      <button class = "btn btn-info btn-sm" name = "edit">Edit</button>     
        </td>

    </tr>

    <?php
        }
?>


</table>


<!------ MODAL'S DIV ("Alter button") ------>
<div id = "basic-modal-content">
    <div id = "titulo"><p>Edit</p></div>

<!---- I would like to populate this form according to what is on the database! ---->
<!---- But I need at least the ID from the clicked line of the table so that I can make a PHP request to the database and get the right data! ---->
    <form style = "margin-left: 50px;">
        <input type = "text" name = "something"/>
    <input type = "text" name = "something"/>
    <input type = "text" name = "something"/>

        <input type = "submit" name = "btnAlterar" value = "Alterar" class = "btn btn-info btn-sm"/>
    </form>
</div>


<!-- This is some jquery to open the modal --->
<script>
    $('[name = "edit"]').click(
        function() {
            $("#basic-modal-content").modal();

        }
    );
</script>
```

Thank you very much! I agree the question is a little bit confusing, but hope you guys can understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On click event you can prepare a data object relevant to client id you just click, a typical row would look like ...

```
 <tr data-row="id_from_db">
    <td name="name1"><?=$client['something']?></td>
    <td name="name2"><?=$client['something']?></td>
    <td name="name3"><?=$client['something']?></td>
    <td name="name4"><?=$client['something']?></td>

<td>
  <!--- How can i get the ID of the client clicked and send to the modal's div form ??--->
  <button class = "btn btn-info btn-sm" name = "edit" data-record="id_from_db">Edit</button>     
    </td>

</tr>
```

Then in your click event, you may proceed to get the record data and apply the prepared data in your form before opening...

```
<script>
 $('[name = "edit"]').click(
    function() {
         var recordno = $(this).attr("data-record");
        var data = getDataFromTable(recordno);
        populateModalForm(data);
        $("#basic-modal-content").modal();

    }
   );


function getDataFromTable(recordno)
{
    var data = {}
    $("[data-row="+recordno+"] td").each(function()
    {
        data[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).html();
    });

    return data;
}

function populateFormData(data)
{
    //select all input elements having name attribute 
    $("#basic-modal-content [name]").each(function()
    {
         $(this).val(data[$(this).name()]);
    })
}
</script>
```

You need to make sure that the names in the table row is mapped correctly to form input name.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
I didn't try exactly like you said, but I could figure out a way and it worked!
Sorry I have not enough reputation to say 'this answer is useful' but thank you!

One more thing, I'm having trouble now get this ID with PHP to fill in the modal's fields... any ideas?

Comment: data-record="id_from_db" in the button stores the id from can be used to store the id from PHP, sample could data-record="<?php echo $id;?>", in click event it is accessed with jquery attr() method

Answer (score 0):

I think when click on edit button you want to put the data to the modal's
 form you created right?

Comment: I understand your sentiments, but its a comment,not an answer to the Orignal Poster's question!

Comment: Sorry I don't have that much reputation to comment.